# Recursion over Iterative solution

Tags: java, recursion

I'm fairly new to recursion and trying out new things while learning it at school. I have submitted my assignment on string reversal using recursion. I was told that I have submitted an Iterative solution and not recursion. I think I did it right. Thoughts?

```
public static String reverse(String s)
    {
        int i=0,j=s.length();
        char[] chars= s.toCharArray();
        while(i<j-1 && i!=j-1)
        {
            char c=chars[i];
            chars[i]=chars[j-1];
            chars[j-1]=c;
            i++;j--;
            reverse(new String(chars).substring(i,j));
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }
```

Comment: A fully recursive solution wouldn't need a while-loop.

Comment: You are calling your own method but you don’t use the result of that method. So you have an iterative solution containing an obsolete method invocation inside the loop.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate There is no `reverse()` in `String` class. Perhaps you meant `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Yupe...Thanks for opening my eye.Misprinted Comment

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the result of the recursive invocation, so its not a pure recursive solution. A pure recursive solution can be :

```
public String reverse(String s)
{
if (s.length() == 0) 
     return s;

return reverse(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this simple code that use recursion

```
public static String reverse(String s){
    return reverse(s.toCharArray(),0,s.length()-1);
}
private static String reverse(char [] chars, int low, int high){
    if(low>=high) return new String(chars);
    char temp = chars[low];
    chars[low]=chars[high];
    chars[high]=temp;
    return reverse(chars,low+1,high-1);
}
```

Otherwise you can also use as argument of the first method s.toCharArray() so you don't have to use a return value ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a recursive algorithm try

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() <= 1) {
    return s;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.substring(
      s.length() - 1, s.length()));
  sb.append(reverse(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)));
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

```
public static String reverse(String s)
{
    if (s.length() == 1)
        return  "";
    else 
       return reverse( s from position 1 to end) + s[0]);
}
```

put your java syntax to deal with the substring ... (haven't touched it in a while)

that's the recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Roughly speaking, recursion and iteration perform the
same kinds of tasks: ! Solve a complicated task one piece at a time, and
combine the results.

**Emphasis of iteration**: ! keep repeating until a task is “done”
e.g., loop counter reaches limit,linked list reaches null pointer,instream.eof() becomes true

**Emphasis of recursion:** ! Solve a large problem by breaking it up into smaller
and smaller pieces until you can solve it; combine the results.

Please see code examples for better understanding:

//--------------- iterative version ---------------------

```
static int FibonacciIterative(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;

    int prevPrev = 0;
    int prev = 1;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        result = prev + prevPrev;
        prevPrev = prev;
        prev = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

//--------------- naive recursive version ---------------------

```
static int FibonacciRecursive(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;

    return FibonacciRecursive(n - 1) + FibonacciRecursive(n - 2);
}
```